# Weird behavior on UILabel with \n on StoryBoard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, uilabel

I want to add a line feed on an `UILabel`. On storyboard using `\n`does not work at all.
Here is an example.

### Adding Labels

On StoryBoard I've created 2 `UILabel` and set their content in dedicated field:

1. `Label 1\nhello` with `\n` created by ALT+RETURN

[image: UILabel 1]

2. `Label 2\nhello` with explicit `\n`

[image: UILabel 2]

3. Then I added a third label and configure it on controller, not on Story Board:

   label3.numberOfLines = 0
   label3.text = "Label3\nhello"

### Context

This is a brand new project, on Xcode 8. Language is Swift 3.1 and AutoLayout is off. So there must not have any interferences from any external libraries, nor AutoLayout.

### Result

Here is the rendering.

[image: Result]

### Conclusion

`UILabel` behavior is not the same if used on StoryBoard or code source and this is really disturbing. Of course while you faced and solved this problem everything seems to be cristal clear, as the answer is known.

This problem is easily solved by using a `UITextView` instead of `UILabel`. So as for now and until I rather prefer using `UITextView` for displaying simple text on multilines despite the fact `UILabel` must work for this purpose.

Comment: @SahebRoy First, I perfectly understand the situation. Second \n does not work in some cases in source codes. I used it for years now and I faced this weird behaviour with no explanations on only few UILabel. A search on this behavior lead to huge amount of questions on SO and others sites. So there really is something wrong on UILabel.

Comment: @SahebRoy This question is not about hank you for you propositions but this is out of scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between the carriage return character (\n) and the characters \n.  The singular character \n is a carriage return and as you have seen splits the line.  However the two characters \ & n just represent the two different characters themselves.

When doing a Storyboard in Interface Builder and characters you enter into a UILabel are all counted as individual characters so if you type \n you are actually entering the character '\' and the character 'n'.  To enter the special single carriage return character (\n) you therefore have to use ALT+RETURN.

Now in code you can be more flexible.  When entering some text like this "Line1\nLine2" the \n is treated as the single carriage return character so to enter the characters '\' & 'n' next to each other you have to use "Line1\nLine2" (the double \ indicates a single '\' character).

So when it works you are getting the single carriage return character (\n) in the string and when it doesn't you are getting the two separate characters.

You don't mention how the \n is added when it doesn't work (outside of a Storyboard) but it must be being added to the string as two separate characters.

As an example:

```
let str1 = "12345\n67890
let str2 = "12345\\n67890
print (str1.characters.count) // prints 11
print (str2.characters.count) // prints 12
```

Comment: Thank you for these explanations. This behavior is still disturbing as there is a difference between Storyboard and code. Of course experience bring this knowledge but for the first time this could be a huge waste of time.i.e. if you copy/paste some text with line feed on it. For the problem on my current problem I am still investigating that's why I did not add details.

Answer (score 9):

In UILabels you simply can't use

> \n

You have to use

> Alt + Enter

to move to the next line.

Comment: should be `option` + Enter

Answer (score 1):

In UILabels you simply can't use

> \n

You have to use

> Option + Enter

to go to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

- New Line From Storyboard:

> Press Ctrl + Enter (between two words)

- New Line From Code:

> Simply Add   "\n"